# Wherever & no matter where

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Sentence 1: **Wherever** he went, he took his dog with him.

Sentence 2: **No matter where** he went, he took his dog with him.

Do the above two sentences have the same meaning?
Do "whatever" and "no matter where" introduce concessive clauses?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, Same meaning!

Answer (score 1):

As JuliandotNut says in the comments, the two sentences mean the same thing.

According to [this definition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/concessive-clause), a concessive clause "contains a fact or idea that seems to oppose the information in the rest of the sentence". But these two clauses aren't really opposing the information in the rest of the sentence. I'd call them adverbial clauses—they tell us something about the verb phrase, "took his dog with him", i.e. that he did this "wherever/no matter where he went".